# C & MinGW: Hello World gives me the error "programm too big to fit in memory"

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

I'm new here. Here's my problem:

I installed MinGW on my Windows 7 Home Premium 32-bit Netbook with Intel Atom CPU N550, 1.50GHz and 2GB RAM.

Now I made a file named hello.h and tried to compile it via CMD with the following command:
"gcc c:\workspace\c\helloworld\hello.h -o out.exe"

It compiles with no error, but when I try to run out.exe, it gives me following error:
**"program too big to fit in memory"**

Things I have checked:

- I have added "C:\MinGW\bin" to the Windows PATH Variable
- I have googled for about one hour, but ever since I'm a newbie, I can't
  really figure out what the problem is.
- I have compiled the same code on my 64-bit machine, compiles
  perfectly, but cannot be run due to 64-bit <-> 16-bit problematic.

I'd really appreciate, if someone could figure out, what the problem is. Btw, here's my hello.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    printf("Hello, World\n");
}
```

... That's it. Thanks for your replies. 
Cheers, Boris

Comment: Probably not the cause of the problem, but you should name your source file `hello.c` instead of `hello.h`. `.h` files are meant for `#include`ing them in other files (usually mostly declarations), whereas `.c` files hold the actual implementations (definitions).

Comment: I just tested this. I get strange errors if I compile this with an .h extension under mingw too.

Comment: Good lord, how can it be? Am I really that dumb? :) Changing the extension to *.c fixed it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: MinGW GCC does not support creating 16-bit applications. Plain MinGW produces 32-bit apps which work just fine on a 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Just rename your file to hello.c

The .h files are headers in C programming and you should put some things like the signatures in them and the body of your methods should be in a .c file

Comment: So what is MinGW doing that causes this bizarro behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

By default, files with `.h` extension are treated as *header* files by GCC. Normally, header files are not supposed to be fed to the compiler directly. They are supposed to be `#include`d into implementation files.

However, GCC implements a special functionality when it sees a header file being fed to it directly. Specifying an `.h` file in the command line makes GCC interpret it as a request to generate a *pre-compiled header file* for that `.h` file. By using an `-o` option you forced the compiler to give the resultant pre-compiled header file a specific name `out.exe`.

Nevertheless, the resultant file is not an executable file, it is a pre-compiled header file. You can open it in a hex editor and see that it begins with `gpch`, which is a GCC's pre-compiler header signature. Any attempts to "execute" that file will lead to meaningless results. (This is basically like trying to rename a completely random file to `.exe` extension and then "running" it.)

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this issue, you have to add the **C:\TDM-GCC-32\bin** to the **%PATH%** variable.
For me it's on E: so it will be: **E:\TDM-GCC-32\bin**
Steps:
**1. Copy the path of TDM-GCC\bin folder**
 [image]

**2. Open Computer Properties**
[image]

**3. Navigate to Advanced**
[image]

**4. Click on Environment Variables button**
[image]

**5. Select variable PATH and click the Edit button**
[image]

**6. Append the copied TDM-GCC path at the end. Don't forget the semicolon.**
[image]

After all of those steps, hit Ok, Ok, Apply, Ok. And you're set!

Here's the result in Command Prompt:
[image]